# Can't load a dataset. Basically the code is not reading a csv file from the particular location in Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm

First thing First
OS - Windows 7 x64 version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 build 7601
Python - 3.6.4 and its 64 bit too.
PyCharm - 2018.1 Community Edition
pandas - 0.23.3
The CSV file is in the same directory where my script is.

So here are now the approaches I implemented :-
Case I:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir("D:\Analyse\ML Algos")
data = pd.read_csv('clients.csv')
```

Case II:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir("D:\Analyse\ML Algos)
data = pd.read_csv(r'clients.csv')
```

Case III:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir("D:\Analyse\ML Algos")
data = pd.read_csv('D:\Analyse\ML Algos\clients.csv')
```

Case IV

```
import pandas as pd
import os
# os.chdir('D:\Analyse\ML Algos')
data = pd.read_csv('D:\\Analyse\\ML Algos\\clients.csv')
```

I've looked the solutions so far on stackoverflow, github but all in vain.

Comment: what do you mean it is "not reading" it? Do you get an error message? If so, edit it into your post.

Comment: Yes.
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: File b'clients.csv' does not exist

Comment: Have you really tried Case II? Because there's a typo...

Comment: Try Case IV with double forward slash

Comment: Try 1:- data = pd.read_csv('D://Analyse//ML Algos//clients.csv')  -> Failed
Try 2:-data = pd.read_csv(r'D://Analyse//ML Algos//clients.csv')  -> Failed

Comment: @JackDaniels: Double forward slashes do not encode directory separators in any programming language.

Comment: I just tried to take a shot !
But nothing...
So What's the alternative for this ?
How !

Comment: So IanS
I did try the case II, with proper caution. It was just that I was typing the code on this website, in this section, so a typo happened !

Now Please Help me !

Comment: Here are your two option
1. csv_file = r'C:\path\to\the\file'
2. csv_file = 'C:\\path\\to\\the\\file''

Comment: @IInspectable my bad. I haven't worked on windows for a long time now

Comment: Now Jack, it's treating it as a string and when I print the data or csv, it prints the string i.e. 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Python3\ml-100k\ml-100k\u.user'

Answer (score 0):

OKay so I finally solved the issue by just, saving the excel sheet into csv format.
 1. Opened the spreadsheet
 2. Saved it as csv

Hence the Problem Solved. Huh!
And By the way, all 4 cases work hale and hearty.
Yup !

Once Again 
Great Thanks to all of you for helping me.